# How can I make a countdown timer in beamer?

Tags: beamer, overleaf

I'm making some integration bee slides by Beamer, but I have trouble creating a timer. I need a countdown timer for each slide (say 2 min and 30 seconds), and automatically go to the next slide when the timer is up (the second slide is the answer of the first slide). After I clicked on the third slide (next question), the countdown timer reset and automatically began.

I've searched for some examples in Overleaf, but the template itself didn't show up correctly in Overleaf. I cannot find any other support (all the timer template seems to be created by the same guy), so I'm here asking for support.

It's not very proud to say it out loud though, I'm a beginner in Beamer, so please leave me some code. It would be fantastic if you make an example based on my request. Also, since I use Overleaf as my compiler, sometimes a code that works elsewhere (say VS Code) might not work for Overleaf. Please give me the Overleaf version, if there's any difference. Thx~

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Both Overleaf and VSCode are just editors. They use the same LaTeX backend (say `xelatex` or `lualatex`). So that should not be a problem.

Comment: Do you need to show the time or would it be enough if the slide changes after 150 seconds? `\begin{frame}
  Problem\pause\transduration{150}
  
  Solution
\end{frame}
`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Overleaf is just an editor that runs (La)TeX under the hood. As long as you use the same version of the same TeX distribution, the result will be the same, regardless of Overleaf or whatever. Overleaf also has in integrated PDF viewer that might not show interactive stuff properly. Your request most probably requires some JavaScript-based solution that might well work in Acrobat Reader, but not necessarily in the integrated viewer on Overleaf or with other PDF viewers.

Comment: Actually, this is more of a PDF question, and probably involves Javascript.  You might look at the eforms package to interface.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/845012/how-can-i-have-a-countdown-timer-stopwatch-in-a-pdf

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes I want to show the time on the slide, both minute and second, and refresh every second, if possible.

Comment: Thank you for leaving comments, but for those taught me to code in Java, I may need more instructions since I really don't know how to do it. (Yes that's why I failed in AP CSA...)

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm sorry, but it seems that I don't have the access to the link. Perhaps you can copy and paste the code here so I can see?

Comment: JavaScript is not Java. But yes, you'd need some more instructions. These would, however, depend on what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: Just visitor's access for me too.  At least you know it is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create your own little countdown using beamer's `\transduration` macro to automatically switch slides (view the pdf with adobe reader in presentation mode):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\countdown}[1]{
  \transduration<1-#1>{1}
  \foreach \macro in {#1,...,1}{\only<+>{\pgfmathparse{int((\macro-mod(\macro,60))/60)}\pgfmathresult:\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\macro,60))}\two@digits{\pgfmathresult}}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Problem 
  
  \countdown{150}
  
  \only<+->{Solution}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With separate frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\countdown}[1]{
  \begin{frame}
  \transduration<1->{1}
  \foreach \macro in {#1,...,1}{\only<+>{\pgfmathparse{int((\macro-mod(\macro,60))/60)}\pgfmathresult:\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\macro,60))}\two@digits{\pgfmathresult}}}
  \end{frame}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\transduration<1->{1}
  Problem 
\end{frame}
\countdown{150}

\begin{frame}
  Solution
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that's so cool, just out of curiosity, what should I do if I want the timer to be not in the same length for different problems? (like for some hard ones, 150 seconds might not be enough...) How can I make the timer variable (I mean if I can set a parameter or something in the "\newcommand" part that I can adjust)

Comment: @JackyWang You could use the duration as an argument of the macro, see my updated answer

Comment: In addition, (I'm not sure if this is a real question though), currently I put my problem and my solution in two different frames, but here you put it in the same one. So does it still work in my pdf? Or should I make any modifications?

Comment: I saw it. Thanks for your work! I gave you a "useful", but I'm new here so, you might receive it later...

Comment: @JackyWang I added a second version with separate frames